# Embedded website in .NET client profile

Tags: .net, iis, webserver

For my desktop application, i'm required to provide an interface that is accessible over the web and runs under the .NET 4.0 client profile (rather than the full version). I could create some kind of WPF or possibly silverlight application however, the requirement is that all common devices should be able to access the application. Therefore a webserver serving HTML seems to be the logical choice.

Practically, i don't need ASP.NET. Some static html pages with resources and a json service would be great. Ideally, i'll build the interface with knockoutjs communicating with a single  json service.

I would not prefer using IIS express since it can't be embedded within my application (deploying my application with a simple click-once installer would be desirable).

I did some checking on Kayak and although it seems to fit my request, it is not very intuitive in serving html pages and their resources (images, css, js etc).

I assume there should be some package perfectly fitting my request but i can't seem to find it.

What would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used Kayak in the past and it's very good, although it seems that [the owner is not maintaining it anymore](http://groups.google.com/group/kayak-http/browse_thread/thread/dc4532e5e56206e1).

You can try the embeddable version of [Microsoft Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx), the debug server for ASP.NET in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, cassini seems great. Didn't know it went opensource. I dont like the dependency on the full .NET framework though. Just for the hope of there being a better solution, i'll wait for some more input. Else i'll build my own serving on top of kayak with the help of the Cassini source.